# Unpivoting two separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, unpivot, lateral-join

I am trying to Unpivot multiple columns from a table.  So far I have tried to just use a standard Unpivot and it is successful for the first part, but not the second. I would like to have both columns Unpivote. I have attached a picture of what I am trying to do. The table has to do with errors. So E1 is short for error1, E2 short for error2 etc...

```
INSERT INTO #tempWorkflowItem
SELECT AssignmentId, Code, Response FROM #temp2
UNPIVOT(Response FOR Code in (E1, E2, E3 ))AS WorkflowItemsUnpivot
UNPIVOT(Reason FOR Code in (E1Reason, E2Reason, E3Reason )) AS WorkflowItemsUnpivot2
```

[image: Table Conversion]

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`:

```
select v.code, v.reason
from #temp2 t cross apply
     (values ('E1', E1Reason), 
             ('E2', E2Reason), 
             ('E3', E3Reason)
     ) v(code, reason, e1, e2, de3);
```

I suspect you also want a `where` clause:

```
where v.code = 'E1' and t.e1 > 0 and
      v.code = 'E2' and t.e2 > 0 and
      v.code = 'E3' and t.e3 > 0 ;
```

or:

```
where v.reason is not null
```

It seems odd to be pulling the `NULL` values back as well.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot that I need the response to the error in my new table as well. I have updated the picture to show what I mean. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `cross apply`:

```
select x.*
from mytable t
cross appy (values 
    ('e1', e1, e1reason),
    ('e2', e2, e2reason),
    ('e3', e3, e3reason)
) x(code, response, reason)
```

Comment: I forgot that I need the response to the error in my new table as well. I updated the picture to show what I mean. I am sorry for not being correct the first time. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Stormfrazier: that's an easy fix to the query. Done.